# Is there any reason not to upload discoveries?

Tags: no-mans-sky

After I discover some waypoints and scan creatures on a planet, I usually upload them for the extra units. However, I've been wondering if there's any reason NOT to upload discoveries. It seems like uploading would happen automatically if it was the only thing that made sense to do. Is there any reason I shouldn't just upload everything I find?

Comment: If you really hated free money, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uploading isn't automatic because you can name them anything you want (within reason). So the only reason not to upload a discovery immediately is if you want to name it something different than the generated name. Otherwise there is not reason to not upload a discovery.

Comment: You can still rename anything after uploading, so really no point in not uploading.

Comment: @Atom do you have instructions on how to do that? I'm not able to rename after uploading.

Comment: @Kat I was wrong, I mistook being able to hold the button and have it register meant you could.

Answer (score 1):

Would "being annoying" be a valid reason? Because I could see uploading stuff manually (even without renaming) becoming a tedious aspect of the game after a while. It's also not terribly profitable.